# join two collections in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, join

I have below two collections

```
db.sample.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5930093eb3aaa7c02d4cbcdc"),
    "name" : "Ashish",
    "posts" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("59301c39028afaf3450e2444"),
                    "post" : ObjectId("59301c39028afaf3450e2885")
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("59301c39028afaf3450e2445"),
                    "post" : ObjectId("59301c39028afaf3450e2889")
            }
     ]
}
```

and other one

```
db.posts.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59301c39028afaf3450e2885"), "title" : "test1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59301c50028afaf3450e2889"), "title" : "test2" }
```

I want to join these two based on matching posts._id & sample.post._id value.
& create structure showing "Title" value as below:
In short create structure which shows post liked  by each user.

```
"name" : "Ashish",
    "posts" : [
            {
                    "post" : ObjectId("59301c39028afaf3450e2889"),
                    "title" :"test2"
            },
                            {
                    "post" : ObjectId("59301c39028afaf3450e2885"),
                    "title" :"test1"
            },
```

Comment: [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). Right up near the top of google search results on your question title. 5th on the list for me, and the top 3 are previous answers on this site and the 4th is MongoDB documentation on the general topic, which then also references `$lookup`. Less time than to type this post.

Answer (score 2):

we can join two collection using $lookup some thing like this

```
db.sample.aggregate([
{
  $lookup:
    {
      from: "posts",
      localField: "posts.post",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "samplepost"
    }
  }
  ])
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: I used your code snippet but Title: "Test1" & Title:"Test2"  field is missing in output.

Comment: samplepost is empty ??

Answer (score 1):

You can test it

```
db.sample.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$posts"},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "posts",
      localField: "posts.post",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "post"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {$first: "$name"},
      posts: {
        $push: {
          post: {$arrayElemAt: ["$post._id", 0]},
          title: {$arrayElemAt: ["$post.title", 0]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```